# What's the difference between Kubernetes and Minikube or Kind?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, minikube

I know, they are basically the same, the difference is when you do it locally and the features kind or Minikube have, but there must be something else right, why do people prefer one or another, how is Kubernetes part of these other two tools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes is the overall project. It's composed of many individual pieces, mostly little Go daemons you need to run, so you need tools to help manage the installation because doing it all by hand would be A Lot™. Minikube and Kind are both tools which help run Kubernetes (all the pieces that make it up) in particular ways. Minikube is aimed at use on a developer workstation to give you a single-node cluster for dev or testing purposes. Kind's original goal was to be a multi-node simulator inside a Docker environment (Kind == Kubernetes in Docker) for CI environments and similar testing of Kubernetes itself, though it's grown a bit beyond that over time and is now also an option for workstation use similar to Minikube if you prefer.